# FLASK: AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'Model'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mysql-connector

I just started learning Flask. I can't figure out how to initialize a mysql database. Do I need to use some version of Alchemy, can I not use mysql modules only instead? I'm getting confused as I google looking any docs on using flask and mysql and I get many hits that include slqalchemy, flask-mysql, flask-mysqldb, flask-mysql-connector. Each example is different and I am going cross-eyed.

With so many examples I suspect my syntax is mixed up. I finally was able to display schemas with following command so I assume am close:

```
# msql_connector.py

from application import mysql


print(mysql)


conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()


cursor.execute('''SHOW SCHEMAS;''')
rv = cursor.fetchall()

for db in rv:
    print(db)
```

However I now want to initialize the db or just be able to write values to it as per below. I am not sure if I actually do need to initialize first or whether I can define the model and add data during runtime.

**My error:**

```
AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'Model'
```

**My main file:**

```
# __init__.py

from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)

from application import routes
```

**Next my DB definitions:**

```
# models.py

import flask
from application import mysql


class User(mysql.Model):

user_id    = mysql.IntField(unique=True )
first_name = mysql.StringField( max_length = 50 )
last_name  = mysql.StringField( max_length = 50 )
email      = mysql.StringField( max_length = 50 )
password   = mysql.StringField( max_length = 50 )

def __init__(self, user_id, first_name, last_name, email, password):
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
```

**My configuration:**

```
# config.py

import os
from flask_mysql_connector import MySQL

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'djfdsjdsj4skldjess85'

    MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost'
    MYSQL_DATABASE_USER = 'flasker'
    MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD = '**********'
    MYSQL_DATABASE_DB = 'UTA_Enrollment'
```

**and last but not least:**

```
import json
from application import app
from application import mysql
from flask import render_template, request, Response
from application.models import User, Course, Enrollment

@app.route("/user")
def user():
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''SHOW SCHEMAS;''')
    rv = cursor.fetchall()

    User(user_id=1, first_name="John", last_name="Doh", email="jd@domain.com", password="abc123")
    User(user_id=2, first_name="Jane", last_name="Doh", email="jad@domain.com", password="abc123")

    users = User.objects.all()

    return render_template("user.html", users=users)
```

So when I go to http://url/user I would like to be able to write the above data into the database.

**My specs:**

```
Python 3.9.6
click==8.1.3
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-MySQL==1.5.2
flask-mysql-connector==1.1.0
Flask-WTF==1.0.1
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.31
numpy==1.24.1
pandas==1.5.2
protobuf==3.20.1
PyMySQL==1.0.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.21.0
pytz==2022.7
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.2.2
WTForms==3.0.1
zipp==3.11.0
```

So to recap:

1. Do I have to use some form of Alchemy to run this type of syntax: title = mysql.StringField( max_length = 100 )
2. am I only limited to running executes as in cursor.execute('''SHOW SCHEMAS;''')
3. do I need to initialize the database (including creating the the tables and fields first?

Answer (score 0):

So I couldnt find the elegant solution for MySQL modules. I went round and round to python-mysql, python-mysql-connector, and flask-msyql. It did turn out that using flask-sqlalchemy was fairly easy to get it to do what I needed.

**pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://..."
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class Course(db.Model):
course_id   = db.Column( db.String(10), primary_key=True )
title       = db.Column( db.String(100), nullable=False )
description = db.Column( db.String(255), nullable=False )
credits     = db.Column( db.String(255), nullable=False )
term        = db.Column( db.String(25), nullable=False )
```